# Mysql Constraint creation fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have on my model these tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `UNIVERSES`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `UNIVERSES` (
  `country_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `order` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`,`code`),
  KEY `identifier` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

ALTER TABLE `UNIVERSES`    
  ADD CONSTRAINT `UNIVERSES_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`) REFERENCES `COUNTRY` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `RULES`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `RULES` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_element_code` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `appliedto_element_code` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

ALTER TABLE `RULES`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from_element_code`) REFERENCES `ELEMENTS` (`code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`appliedto_element_code`) REFERENCES `ELEMENTS` (`code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `RULES_TYPE` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And I need to add one field with a constraint. I try:

```
--
-- Add new field to RULES table
--

ALTER TABLE `RULES` ADD `univers_code` VARCHAR(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL AFTER `appliedto_element_code`;
ALTER TABLE `RULES` ADD `country_code` VARCHAR(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL AFTER `appliedto_element_code`;

--
-- Create new index for new RULES field
--

ALTER TABLE `RULES`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`, `univers_code`) REFERENCES `UNIVERSES` (`country_code`, `code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And fields are created, but the constraint fails with the following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CFS_DEV`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-aac_145'>, CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`, `univers_code`) REFERENCES `UNIVERSES` (`country_code`, `code`) ON UPDATE C)
```

I have watched types match, and since it is a double primary-key, that pair is unique and indeed it is the primary-key of the referenced table. I don't know what I am skipping.

Please, one help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: mysql engine output**

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140826 18:55:17 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 25649B, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 2732, OS thread id 2825907056 inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
5 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 349, query id 19960 192.168.230.1 mdecfs01 copy to tmp table
ALTER TABLE `RULES`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`univers_code`) REFERENCES `UNIVERSES` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
Foreign key constraint fails for table `CFS_DEV`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-aac_15d'>:
,
  CONSTRAINT `RULES_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`univers_code`) REFERENCES `UNIVERSES` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
Trying to add in child table, in index `RULES_ibfk_4` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000023; asc    #;;

But in parent table `CFS_DEV`.`UNIVERSES`, in index `identifier`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 41; asc A;;
 1: len 2; hex 6265; asc be;;
```

Comment: `show engine innodb status` has a "last foreign key error" section buried about 1/2 way down the output. it'll have details of why the constraint failed.

Comment: thank you Marc, I was on that task while you wrote. Can you see something ? I can't :(

Comment: You've got some dangling records. e.g. a child record would have no parent records, so the whole FK operation is aborted.

Comment: an idea how to solve ? I am not sure to understand what dangling records means

Comment: figure out which records in `rules` don't have matching records in `universes`. e.g. do a joined query between the two and see which ones have `null` on one side of the results. you COULD disable foreign key verification temporarily while doing the alters, but then you've just done the equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: recreating the structure form scratch works, but the model is with data and I can't drop and recreate. Maybe disable the FK verification is all I can do. I will try. Thank you.